# Trigger each div independently using same script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to get each blue div (`<div id="rectangle"></div>`) to fire independently.

Right now, if you hover/click over the first one, both fire simultaneously, and if you hover/click over the second one, neither fires.

This is a common question and has been addressed elsewhere, but I've tried to implement several different versions and apply it to this particular code, and it's not working. I was hoping someone could provide some explanation to help me learn, and I can compare to the other posts I've tried out to understand what the difference is.

```js
$('.rectangle1').hide();
  $('#rectangle').on('click', function() {
    clicked = !clicked;
  });

  $('#rectangle').hover(function() {
    $('.rectangle1').slideDown()
  },function() {
    if (!clicked) {
      $('.rectangle1').slideUp()
    }
  });  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="rectangle"></div>
<div class="rectangle1"></div>

<div id="rectangle"></div>
<div class="rectangle1"></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Q5cRU/99/

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you're using the same `id` twice?

Comment: Duplicate ids are invalid, use class=rectangle instead.  Your hover function uses code that tells every .rectangle1 to slide up or down, not just the one immediately following the hovered element.  Clicked looks like a global variable, so it will be shared between all the rectangles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is simple: The event listener was only applied to the first `#rectangle`. jQuery does not select more than one `#ID`'d element. With that being said it is not semantic to use the same `id` on more than one `element`.

Here's what you are looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/Q5cRU/116/

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.rectangle1').hide();

    $('.rectangle').data( 'clicked', false).click(function() {

       $(this).data( 'clicked', !$(this).data('clicked'));

    }).hover(
      function() {

        $(this).next('.rectangle1').slideDown();

      },
      function() {

          if (!$(this).data('clicked')) {

             $(this).next('.rectangle1').slideUp();

          }
      }
    );  
});

$("div.rectangle1").mouseover(function() {
  $(this).stop(true, true).show();
});
```

Comment: Got it. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 2):

One problem is that you're using `id="rectangle"` for two elements. [According to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id):

> The id global attribute defines a unique identifier (ID) which must be unique in the whole document.

jQuery is only adding the event listeners to the first element with that ID.

Answer (score 1):

Well in HTML, the id attribute must be unique per element. [See this](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_id.asp). The class attribute can be shared by multiple elements to have the same style effect or same purpose. So the first and second div can't have the same id - "rectangle". To fire event independently you can assign different id for them.

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<div>
    <div class="rectangle"></div>
    <div class="rectangle-hover"></div>
</div>

<div>
    <div class="rectangle"></div>
    <div class="rectangle-hover"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.rectangle {
   width: 140px; 
   height: 80px;
   background: #037CA9;
  margin-bottom:10px;
}

.rectangle-hover {
   width: 140px; 
   height: 150px;
   background: red;
}
```

Javascript:

```
$(function(){

    var clicked = false;

    $('.rectangle-hover').hide();

    $('.rectangle').hover(
        function(){
            $(this).parent().find('.rectangle-hover').slideDown();
        },
        function(){
            if (!clicked) {
                $('.rectangle-hover').slideUp()
            }
        }
    );

});
```